# Algorithm for calculating all intersects and disjoints for an indefinite number of sets

Tags: algorithm, set

Recently I had to develop a naive recursive algorithm for the set problem outlined below, but would now like to know what the formal description/name of the problem is and whether there's an algorithm that allows the problem to be solved more efficiently (I suspect there is).

I know there are separate algorithms for finding intersects and disjoints, but I haven't recognized any that cover this problem as a whole.

The problem:

To take an indefinite number of sets and return one set for each intersect and non-intersect of all the sets.

For example, given 4 sets as input A,B,C,D:

A {1,14,2,10,13,12,8,9}

B {2,3,4,15,11,13,9}

C {13,10,4,15,5,6,12,11}

D {7,8,9,13,11,6,12}

[image]

The result should be the following 13 sets:

{1,14},{2},{3},{4,15},{5},{6},{7},{8},{9},{10},{11},{12},{13}

[image]

The algorithm I developed was naive in that it compared all set permutations recursively (I wanted to be able to implement this relatively easily in XSLT 2.0) until no further intersects were found.

Some context, I needed to perform this operation to describe how multiple versions of a tree modify the original tree, at each point on the tree. The 'tree' is actually an XML document.

[Update]
Showing the 1st algorithm in the accepted answer run against the 3 sets:
{1,2,3},{2,3,4},{2,3,5}

[image]

Compared to my original nieve algorithm run over the 3 sets:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem becomes quite easy, once some set property are clear.

```
A int B int C = ( A int B ) int C
```

what this tells us is that we can solve the problem for 2 sets, and then intersect every result with the the third set, and so on.

By solving hte problem, I mean simply that, `A int B` generates 3 sets:

```
A op B => A int B , A - (A int B) , B - (A int B)
```

once this is clear, the implementation comes simply, and should look like:

```
resultset = emptyset
while ( queue not empty )
   tmpset = emptyset
   A = queue.pop()
   residual = A
   for B in resultset
     tmpset = tmpset + {A int B , B - (A int B)}
     residual = residual - B
   tmpset = tempset + residual
   resultset = tmpset
```

obviously if any of the set is empty, it doesn't need to be added to the solution.
This is some C# code that solves the problem using the dictionary idea:

```
        var query = arr.Select((x, i) => x.Select(y => new { Elem = y, Index = i }))
            .SelectMany(x => x)
            .GroupBy(x => x.Elem)
            .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => new HashSet<int>(y.Select(z => z.Index).ToList()))
            .GroupBy(x => x.Value, HashSet<int>.CreateSetComparer())
            .Select(x=>x.Select(y=>y.Key).ToList())
            .ToList();
```

Comment: +1 because you've described the 'nieve' solution I used better than I could have (though I'm not familiar with the implementation language you're using), but is there a name for this problem and is there a more efficient algorithm that avoids testing all permutations?

Comment: Just to add that while it's true that A int B generates 3 sets as you state, the 3rd set may be an empty set if A is a subset of B or vice versa

Comment: It's pseudocode, just some sort of mix between real code and english. I don't think this problem has a specific name, and I'm quite sure you can't do better than this. Just to make it clear tho, you are not testing all the permutations. Another approach may be, crete a dictionary like structure and add one element at the time, with a list of the sets where he belong. once you have that, creating the partition is quite easy.

Comment: Yes, hadn't noticed it's not testing all permutations - I will test this out further with a few examples.

Comment: I have added some actual c# code that solves your problem in a "smart" way. I hope it helps

Comment: Yes, sorry, the text should have mirrored the pictures, the 14 in B should have actually been 4 - I've corrected the question

Comment: When you state `A int B => A int B , A - (A int B) , B - (A int B)` - should it actually be: `A op B => A int B , A - (A int B) , B - (A int B)` - where 'op' is the operation (not an intersect)?

Comment: (deleted this comment)

Comment: @pgfearo yes, by on the left side of the equation I mean what you call op, and with + I mean "add to the set". In your case, tmpset will be a set of sets.

Comment: I've updated my question with a sample run against your 1st algorithm compared to the original nieve one that I was using

Comment: Ignore the previous comment, I guess hte second image shows your former algorithm :) By the way, I think the second algorithm should be even faster, since the toal cost is basically 2 groupings.

Comment: Yes, second image does show my nieve algorithm - just to contrast. I will try your 2nd algorithm, but would want to use XSLT 3.0 maps for this as XSLT 2.0 (which I'm currently using) would require a fair amount of extra code.